# how do I free environ that allocated using malloc befor exec

Tags: c, shell, exec

I'm writing a shell that mimics some basic funciton of a real shell, and I'm trying to add environ in my shell so that child process can inherit a copy of parent's environment.

```
int Execute(char *argList[]) {
    int pid;
    int wstatus;
    int ret;
    pid = fork();
    if (!pid) {
        environ = VTable2Environ();
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
        execvp(argList[0], argList);
        perror("execvp");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid != -1) {
        ret = wait(&wstatus);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("wait");
            return -1;
        } else {
            return wstatus;
        }
    } else {
        perror("fork");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

function `VTable2Environ()` returns a `char **environ`, which is allocated using malloc, and copying global variable from the process's variable table.

```
char **VTable2Environ(){
    char **env = malloc(sizeof(Variable) * (varTableSize + 1));
    if(!env)return NULL;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < varTableSize; ++i){
        if(varTable[i].scope == GLOBAL){
            env[j++] = varTable[i].str;
        }
    }
    env[j] = NULL;
    return env;
}
```

I want to avoid memory leak.And according to execve(2)

> execve() does not return on success, and the text, data, bss, and
> stack of the calling process are overwritten by that of the program
> loaded.

It seems like `environ` is not overwritten by `execve()`. So do I need to free it? if so, how?

Comment: You don't even use `environ`.  Was that call to `execvp` supposed to be `execle`?

Comment: No, it's a example code from the book I'm reading, I know exec family function with suffix -e take environ as argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to `free` anything. If `exec*` was successful you do not need to free memory, and if it failed, you're running that `exit(1)` in the *child process* which allocated the memory in the first place, and you do not need to free memory.

Another thing is that you do not need to modify the original environment! The `execvpe` function accepts a 3rd argument which is `char **environ`; you can use this to pass in another environment. As a bonus *your* PATH can be different from the executed process' PATH.

Therefore you can write

```
char **newEnv = VTable2Environ();
execvpe(argList[0], argList, newEnv);
```

Comment: so environ is no different than some malloc allocated space on heap right?

Comment: @zenxy If you mean the _initial_ value of the `environ` pointer, the memory is more like that pointed to by the `argv` parameter of `main()`. It isn't something that can be passed to `free()` or `realloc()`, so in that sense is different to space allocated by `malloc()`.